# Find $k$:$\frac{1}{a+b+kab}+\frac{1}{c+b+kcb}+\frac{1}{a+c+kac}\ge \frac{3}{k+2},$ for $ab+bc+ca=3.$

Tags: inequality

Finding all real value of constant $k$ such that$$\frac{1}{a+b+kab}+\frac{1}{c+b+kcb}+\frac{1}{a+c+kac}\ge \frac{3}{k+2},$$
holds for all $a,b,c\ge 0$ satisfying $ab+bc+ca=3.$

I think equality case is $a=b=\sqrt{3};c=0$ and pers.

My strategy is spliting some cases

- $a+b+kab>0$
- $a+b+kab<0$
  But I don't know exactly what to to in each case.

Hope to see some help. Thank you.

Comment: I saw something ugly

Comment: @Anonymous Maybe it means that the equality case $c=0$ and $a=b=\sqrt3$?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg What does that mean ? Could you please tell more ?

Comment: @Anonymous See your open post. You wrote: $c=0$ and $a=b=1$. But the condition is $ab+ac+bc=3$.

Comment: I had a mistake. Thank you, I'll fix

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Could you please give me a hint ?

Comment: For $k\geq0$ we can use $uvw$. If $k\leq0$, so easy to show that $k\geq-\frac{2}{\sqrt3}.$

Comment: It seems that the answer is: $\left[-\frac{2}{\sqrt3},\frac{-\sqrt3+1-\sqrt{13-7\sqrt3}}{\sqrt3}\right]\cup\left[\frac{-\sqrt3+1+\sqrt{13-7\sqrt3}}{\sqrt3},+\infty\right)$, but all these is very ugly. I think.